# Accidentally created submodule folders in GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

Hello I uploaded these files to GitHub and now they are grey and unclickable. I believe they are called submodules, but I am not sure what happened. Should I delete the local and remote repository and try again? What commands should I type in the terminal to fix this? I am new to uploading files to GitHub. I think I may have created repositories in repositories.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Each of those ‘folders’ is a submodule.

You’ll need to unregister each submodule with

```
git submodule deinit -f path/to/submodule
```

You can then either delete the folder if you don’t want the contents, or delete the `.git` folder within `path/to/submodule` to use the contents as a normal folder within the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the folders I was trying to upload already had hidden .git folders which was causing directories in directories when trying to upload to GitHub via the command line. Simply pressing *Shift + Command + .* on my Mac showed these hidden .git folders, and I went through and deleted all of them, which fixed my problem.